# How to do a final summary for N groups in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, summary

I would like to know how to make a dynamic summary for N group changes in the report footer, but I don't find a way to do it like a list evaluating every group change, for example:

```
Group A:
Item   Price
-Apple 200
-Pear 100
Total: 300
-----------
Group B:
Item   Price
-Banana 25
-Mango 15
Total: 40
-------
...
-------
Group N:
Item   Price
- Lemon 30
- Watermelon 75
Total: 105
```

Report footer:

```
Totals:
Group A:300
Group B:40
...
Group N: 105
```

I use summary fields in the group footer conditioned to reset when the group changes.

The idea is to make a list with the totals for every grouped records in the report. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert a CrossTab in the report footer.
Select the row (in your case, the Grouping field/formula) and the item to summarize.  Voila!